# Deep-copying unique_ptrs to pmr resources (using pmr allocators)

Tags: c++, c++20, copy-constructor, unique-ptr, c++pmr

I rewrote my library based on polymorphic memory resources. I think they're amazing, however there are edge cases that are not really covered by the standard.

For example just now I have the following problem: A class type holds an `unique_ptr` to a pmr-allocated resource. Now, how to deal with this in the copy constructor? The underlying pmr-resource (a `pmr::vector`) will have to be constructed using the pmr-resource (which is passed down automatically using the pmr allocators I think). So I'm using the `new_object()` and `delete_object()` facilities of the allocator to feed my unique ptr. But it fails because 1) allocators are not delete-functors (don't provide `operator()` overload for delete) and/or 2) I can't use a function directly because those functions are non-static. How do I resolve this?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwA7KSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4BwemZjgLhkTEs8YlcKXaYDtlCBEzEBLk%2BfkG2mPYlDE0tBGXRcQnJts2t7fldCpNDESOVYzUAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/hHI3lgA1Cb%2BbmwsJACeAPrEmAqb25jn2CYaAIL7h8eYZwuV1u70%2BP2%2Bc2IXgcJ1SxFQNHoYJMgSs3xOGJOXkyRhOYloqFERGIdwIN1SAPOABETnN0CAQKkWIlGZ4btdiKkEHhkHd8YSmMTzm46QzYjcCG9/B9/GivpjYfDEZgIPyiSRSeSAWrBSRATSUVZAlTVmCFQqQJidcS7obrSQUVSzZjDY7kejMXCEXQVWgGHNFd6kWYAGwnVAEBAJUh42gE9UkskU2Px3XEfVnVGO00e80nS0Y%2B0kw0pgXEzNO3OZuV5jEAejrJypmEwqROaFSNxOADd6kKqwqmF4iCcqBnRYzmQz0rR2SQuTy%2BXGyw6LhPxZL3gysPRJXdULFtH3zjXa92xAo7uOCPSQF4GHgAI5eTB3VIEYjCr3KmNYI5JlVzBDKhTWlEsizuAA6SIAHd90PY8Lm/H13ggdZRwrE9nQxN1vmw0sE01ZNgEwAgl1TYk0OrfCFUeAgtgYAi01tWV8Nw8F5StZdCIApibSwqsJ3vJ8XzfD9hQnJkWV7BxVzcdBNliJEwOlHsLxYuU3VYvCdK%2BCICBOFgmAiNDkSzKtkPoWEBI4hVLIBVBDVSLTNONDh1loTgAFZeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrFpF4djOMx/B4UgCE0dz1gAaxALyNH0ThJF8hLAs4XgFBAdL4v89zSDgWAYEQFBUBYVIfTICgIDQWr6pQAwjFJKEGCSvg6ElYgCogWIctiCIWhuThYuathBAAeQYWccqwIyjHEErSHwR4Gl7Ar1swVR6mHXYAv0noctoPBYmIcaPCwHKPzwFhJtKqgDGABQADU8EwGDZopPzYv4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdR1t0Lh9EMYxQssfRLoKyB1lQd9sl2gBaXG6WpUxLGsMwNBOXGAHV8Qp2aFHyno%2B2yFwGHcTwOj0MJFgqKo9CKLIBGmPx4f5vphh5lZul6Rp5iFvQ6gaAQBlacXRmqCZBjl%2BG5kGVXlmqdZni2HY9A/Ftno87zsvWoKOFUAAOENcZDSR23a4ATggD97yS1ZPZCkmUZOXBCD1fZ4ZODwWvodNw9WXhiq0VZ1ijJgsESNCMo4LLSCetLSD8gLbfywq4oS9ZyqqzYCFSYdyEoZq6pjqJWF2B2nZdk5gGQZATi4MxILMXhMHwYk8HpeGgeEURxHBqeobUHK4dIGDrtSC2s58guctt2bh1rgyEROdvnddo5Ec973ur9iAo6bhIopi%2BOy5K5PSBS/PPOz3g8/SwveGLrYUuidErv1SulL%2B/hrZFzyi/JOlsOBD23jbWBIC369gGszSQQA)

```
#include <memory_resource>
#include <memory>

struct profile
{
    using allocator_type = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;
    profile(allocator_type allocator = {})
        :   allocator_{allocator}
    {}

    profile(const profile& other, allocator_type allocator = {})
        :   allocator_{ allocator }
    {
        // Deep copy vector (how to do this?)
        auto f = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>::delete_object;
        vals_ = std::unique_ptr<profile, decltype(&f)>{ allocator_.new_object<profile>(), f };
    }

    allocator_type get_allocator() {
        return allocator_;
    }

    allocator_type allocator_;
    std::unique_ptr<std::pmr::vector<double>> vals_;
};


int main()
{
    profile p;

    profile o{p};
}
```

Error:

```
<source>:15:62: error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
        auto f = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>::delete_object;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Why do you actually use a `unique_ptr` instead of `std::pmr::vector` directly for  `vals_` ?

Comment: @wohlstad that is a contrived example. In reality I'm using a much bigger type that itself contains a vector and so on. I want to pass ownership around without infering too much overhead.

Comment: I think you need to provide a few more details. First, there's no indication of how `vals_` will actually be set to a non-null value in the first place. In other words, where does the `std::pmr::vector<double>` come from? Second, is the actual type (that `std::pmr::vector<double>` is apparently standing in for here) polymorphic, or is there some other reason why you need the indirection? Is it expensive to move?

Comment: @BrianBi What I abstracted here as vector will actually be a struct containing a lot of data along with a vector. vals_ will be assigned to repeatedly during runtime. I think the move is expensive, however I didn't test it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <memory_resource>
#include <memory>

struct profile
{
    using allocator_type = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;
    
    // This is a method
    // std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>::delete_object<std::pmr::vector<double>>
    // so if you want the unique_ptr to have deleter use this method you must
    // also provide it the polymorphic_allocator that it should call this method on
    // BUT
    // you don't actually even need a unique_ptr to solve the problem
public:    
    
    profile(allocator_type allocator = {})
        : allocator_{allocator}
    {}

    profile(const profile& other, allocator_type allocator = {})
        : allocator_{ allocator }
        , vals_(std::begin(other.vals_), std::end(other.vals_), allocator_)
    {
    }

    allocator_type get_allocator() {
        return allocator_;
    }

    allocator_type allocator_;
    std::pmr::vector<double> vals_;
};


int main()
{
    profile p;

    profile o{p};
}
```

The unique_ptr was redundant as it was just doing ptr->ptr->actual data
Now it is ptr->data.
Regarding move/copy construction -> copy construction using the same instance of allocator will behave correctly (std::vector is allocator aware container)
same will go for different instance of allocator (second constructor) ->
you're delegating the tedious work of implementing  Allocator Aware Container (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSWfushlvB8) to the actual container in the class -> std::vector
Obviously std::move for instances of profile (or even instances of internal vector) would be handled correctly.

If you have a use case that would require that unique_ptr it would become a lot more complicated. unique_ptr has a following template signature:

```
template<class T, class Deleter>
class unique_ptr{[...]};
```

It doesn't do any type erasure so every time you would pass around instance of this class it would require you to provide the deleter as a template argument

This is different in case of shared_ptr which has following signature:

```
template<class T>
class shared_ptr{[...]};
```

Even though there is no template argument corresponding to deleter it allows usage of them (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

So assuming this use case you would need to create a function like object of known type that would be the the Deleter type argument, however this comes with several disadvantages:

- Requires you to implement AllocatorAwareContainer
- Massively complicates the logic of the class
- Isn't a good code practice (as you are merging two functionalities inside class that was probably not targeted to be specifically a container of arbitrary data)

Comment: Thank you, that's the point. My class is more complicated than just a vector handler. As unique_ptr doesn't store the allocator, I need to carry it around externally. I thought about using std::bind bound to the specific allocator instance but that really makes it way more complicated. Also I would have to store the std::bind wrapper in the class so the lifetime matches that of the unique_ptr. I can however not figure out how to set this up correctly right now